# Strange Pattern on Automotive PCB

Tags: pcb-design, automotive, pcb-fabrication

What is the purpose of the following shape / item on PCB.
Could this be a FR4 or Conductive Layer quality control related thing?

Top Side:

> Point inside the rectangle connected to some tray (The Point is not connected to the device - NOT an ESD connection point)

[image]

Bottom Side:

> Rectangle Pad on exact opposite, same size as on the top, but filled in Copper (No Gold Plate as on other PADs)

[image]

The PCB comes from Car switch, it also has galvanic plated gold on the other contact pads.

Comment: It could be a test point or a pad to connect scope clip. Or its a contact for add-on switch

Comment: "The Point is not connected to the device" what do you exactly mean by that? There certainly is a trace going to it.

Comment: @Arsenal - I meant it's not connected to any Housing/Casing as its usually done to ground something.